# Динамическое создание item в ListView

Tags: android, listview

Нужно в `ListView`, в каждом `item` выводить разное количество View- элементов (у этого ListView, в каждом item разное количество песен).
Вариант создать это программно в цикле, хотелось бы узнать о правильной реализации.

Делаю так:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {         
ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null){  
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx   
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.internetlist, viewGroup, false); 
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();            
    viewHolder.txtItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.internetlistText);   
    viewHolder.image = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.internetlistImageView1);
    viewHolder.layot = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.internetlistLinearLayout1);
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);        
    }
    else {            
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();        
    }
      //viewHolder.txtItem.setText(objects.get(position).getItems().get(0).getUrl());
    if (viewHolder.image!=null){
    //new DownloadImageTask(viewHolder.image).execute(objects.get(position).getItems().get(0).getUrl());
    viewHolder.txtItem.setText(objects.get(position).getItems().get(1).getArtist());
    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(objects.get(position).getItems().get(0).getUrl(),viewHolder.image,options);
        for (int i =1;i<objects.get(position).getItems().size();i++){
            Button b = new Button(ctx);
            b.setBackgroundResource(R.color.ffffff);
            b.setTextSize(15);


            b.setText(objects.get(position).getItems().get(i).getArtist() + " " +objects.get(position).getItems().get(i).getTitle());
            viewHolder.layot.addView(b);
        }
    }
    return convertView;
```

Кнопки создаются, заполняются правильно, только при скроллинге появляется лишние списки (например, в первом  `item` - первый список песен и там же третий или пятый и так везде). Может это связано с пересозданием `item`?

И еще вопрос. Можно мои динамически созданные кнопки как то хранить в `Holder`?

Comment: Если вы вьюхолдер получили из тэга то вам нужно вызвать у viewHolder.layot removeAllViews

Answer (score 1):

Сделат так, вроде работает

```
   public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {         
ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null){  
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx   
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.internetlist, viewGroup, false); 
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();            
    viewHolder.txtItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.internetlistText);   
    viewHolder.image = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.internetlistImageView1);
    viewHolder.layot = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.internetlistLinearLayout1);

    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);        
    }
    else {            
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();        
    }
      //viewHolder.txtItem.setText(objects.get(position).getItems().get(0).getUrl());
    if (viewHolder.image!=null){

    viewHolder.layot.removeAllViews();
    //new DownloadImageTask(viewHolder.image).execute(objects.get(position).getItems().get(0).getUrl());
    viewHolder.txtItem.setText(objects.get(position).getItems().get(1).getArtist());
    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(objects.get(position).getItems().get(0).getUrl(),viewHolder.image,options);
        for (int i =1;i<objects.get(position).getItems().size();i++){
            View item = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.internetitemtitle, null, false);
            TextView t = ((TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.internetitemtitleTextView1));
            TextView t1 = ((TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.internetitemtitleTextView2));

            //Button b = new Button(ctx);
            //b.setBackgroundResource(R.color.ffffff);
            //b.setTextSize(15);
            //b.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            //viewHolder.title.setFontFeatureSettings("sans-serif-thin");
            //viewHolder.title.setText(position+"");
            t.setText(objects.get(position).getItems().get(i).getTitle());
            t1.setText(objects.get(position).getItems().get(i).getArtist());
```

musicposit.item = position;
    musicposit.music = i;
    item.setTag(musicposit);
                viewHolder.layot.addView(item);
            }
        }
        return convertView;
static class MusicPosit{
        int item;
        int music;
    }

Теперь другая проблема, получается каждий item сожержит список с песнями. Мне нужно при нажатии на песню отловить две цифри: позицию item и позицию песню в item.

Comment: используйте setTag для item, напишите класс который будет хранить 2 поля, позицию элемента и позицию песни. перед добавлением в лэяут устанавливайте этот обьек в качестве тега по аналогии вьюхолдера. при клике на элемент получаете тег.

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ, я обновил, сделал, как вы сказали. А вытягивать данные так? MusicPosit musicposit = (MusicPosit)v.getTag();

Comment: да так если онкликлистенер вы вешали на `item`

Comment: При попытке вывести musicposit.item выбивает ошибка. И ещё вопрос, еслии класс static у него может быть только один экземпляр т.е.Musicposit musicposit = (MusicPosit)v.getTag(); это тот musicposit, который писали в settag

Comment: это абсолютно тот объект, ошибка у вас потому что вы не у того вью берете тег и вы получаете NPE.

Comment: В ответах нельзя задавать вопросы. Создавайте новый вопрос с новой проблемой.

Comment: Позицию item выводит правильно,  а вот позицию песни в item выводит всегда последней. Что это может быть?

Answer (score 0):

Можно, например, у элементов `ListView` положить `LinearLayout` с вертикальной ориентацией `android:orientation="vertical"`. Уже потом, в адаптере, куда передан `List` ваших объектов, в свою очередь которые имеют свои списки с названиями песен, так вот по этим спискам циклом покласть их на Ваш layout.

Comment: Обновил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста